# Remove duplicate entries from PowerShell object while keeping PSObject intact

Tags: powershell, duplicates, psobject

I have created a PSObject with multiple properties. I would like to remove duplicate entries from the PSObject using a specific property as a reference.

I'd like to do this while keeping the PSObject in its original format.

Examples I have seen extract the non-duplicate values. I want to delete the duplicate values.

I'm trying to turn this:

```
DistinguishedName                             Name    
-----------------                             ----
OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Local                   Users
OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Local                   Users
```

Into this:

```
DistinguishedName                             Name    
-----------------                             ----
OU=Users,DC=Domain,DC=Local                   Users
```

I have a feeling i'm missing a trick here...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the `Format-Table` output of a *collection* of PSObjects with the same properties.

To weed out duplicates, use `Sort-Object -Unique`:

```
$uniqObjects = $psobjects |Sort-Object -Unique
```

Comment: Apologies yes I meant a collection of PSObjects. That worked great! Thanks very much.